# Как в react вызывать функцию только при перезагрузке страницы

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

У меня есть функция которая берет данные с json файла fetchPosts().Однако мой json файл постоянно обновляется и это приводит к тому что страница постоянно перезагружается сама по себе. Как сделать чтобы данная функция вызывалась только при перезагрузке сайта пользователем? Есть отдельно сервер на node js который пасит информацию с сайтов и постоянно перезаписывает json файл.Если я делаю что то не так, подскажите пожалуйста как правильно реализовать отправку данных на сайт. По сути это должен быть обычный агрегатор новостей. Заранее спасибо

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Post from './components/Post';
import axios from 'axios';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
var fs = require("fs");
var stringify = require('json-stringify-safe');

class App extends Component {
  Update(){
      fs.writeFileSync('C:/Users/ablya/new-app/public/resultBask.json',"HHHH",err => {
          if(err) console.log('NOT Saved');
        });

  }
  fetchPosts() {
    const { setPosts } = this.props;
    setPosts([]);
  fetch('./result.json').then(response => {
          console.log("SSSSSSSSS"+response);
          return response.json();
        }).then(data => {
          setPosts(data);

        }).catch(err => {
          console.log("Error Reading data " + err);
        });
  }

  componentWillMount(){
    this.fetchPosts();
  }
  render() {
    const { posts } = this.props;
    const { items } = posts;
    return (
      <div>
        <div>

          <h3>Спортивные новости: {this.props.regions.region}а</h3>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <button onClick={() => this.props.changeRegion('Футбол')}>
                Футбол
              </button>
            </li>
            <li>
              <button onClick={() => this.props.changeRegion('Баскетбол')}>
                Баскетбол
              </button>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        {!items.length ? (
          <span>Loading...</span>
        ) : (
          items.map(({ title, text, image }, key) => (
            <Post
              key={key}
              title={title}
              text={text}
              image={image}
            />
          ))
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
const state = props => {
  return {
    ...props,
  };
};

const actions = dispatch => ({
  setPosts: data =>
    dispatch({
      type: 'SET_POSTS',
      payload: data,
    }),
  changeRegion: name =>
    dispatch({
      type: 'CHANGE_REGION',
      payload: name,
    }),
});

export default connect(state, actions)(App);
```

Comment: Рекомендую вам переходить на хуки. Для классов используется componentDidMount насколько я помню.

Answer (score 0):

1. componentWillMount - (просто напоминаю, что это deprecated метод), при его использовании для axios или fetch, метод не будет ожидать выполнения запроса по природе асинхронности js, т.е. компонент хоть раз, но отобразится с пустыми данными, следовательно п.2 более приемлем. Ну и рендер из-за этого может, как в Вашем случае уйти в вечный луп
2. componentDidMount - данный метод жизненного цикла выполнится только один раз, после рендера, поэтому стоит правильно настроить state компонента
3. Ну или используйте хуки - useEffect

Answer (score 0):

По мне самый простой вариант решения, это просто закинуть метод onload на div страницы. Грубо говоря просто:

```
 <div onLoad={this.fetchPosts}>
        ...
 </div>
```

единственное что нужно будет сделать, это у вас функцию обозначить как:

```
fetchPosts = () => { 
    //do smth...
}
```